# All HTTP client applications appear broken

Tags: networking, 13.10

I am using 13.10 on my laptop. All of my HTTP applications seem to have stopped working. I can ssh and ping as usual. DNS is resolving fine using dig. So it does not seem to be a network or DNS problem. As far as I know there is no proxy server configured, and other computers on the same wifi network (i.e. the one I am on now) are working fine. However firefox, wget and apt-get have all stopped working.

Firefox just shows the page loading animation forever, wget is stuck at "HTTP request sent, awaiting response", and apt-get gets stuck at "waiting for headers".

I suspect this might be related to an update from ubuntu. Perhaps some library they all use is broken?

Any ideas what might be going on? Or how to diagnose this issue?

Comment: I can also use nc to connect to google and manually issue an HTTP request, and I get a response OK. So its not a networking issue.

Comment: What output do you get from `netstat -an | grep :80`?

Comment: There are two established connections to ip address off my network, that don't reverse resolve in DNS

Comment: Adding -p switch one is "firefox" process and another is "python3" process. I guess th firefox one is the one related to the firefox tab that is stuck loading. It is like the HTTP request is sent but not response comes back...